# Load shell_default module in remote shell

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell, erl

When I run the `erl` shell my `.erlang` file is evaluated and loads in my `shell_default` module (`shell_default:c(ShellDefaultFilePath).`). I can use all the functions defined in my `shell_default` module directly in the shell. In a remote shell the functions from my `shell_default` are not present. My remote shell (remsh) is connected to an Erlang node on a remote host via SSH port forwarding so I thought it may have been evaluating the `.erlang` file on the remote server, but I verified that my local `.erlang` file is evaluated by adding an `io:format/2` call to the end of the file and I saw the message printed out when I start the remsh.

Why aren't my `shell_default` functions not loaded in remote shells? And is there a workaround to get my `shell_default` functions loaded?

Comment: Where is the `.erlang` file located in the remote host? Is it in the home folder of the user that starts the Erlang VM? The `.erlang` in your local host won't make any difference when connecting to the remote Erlang node with the `-remsh` option.

Comment: @juan.facorro The remote node is on a different server, and I'm not sure what the contents of it were when I discovered this. It still seems odd that my local `.erlang` file was evaluated. I'll try setting up the `.erlang` file and `shell_default` module on the remote server and see if that fixes the issue.